# How to print string variable as f string in python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, f-string

i want to print my user variable from my python script to a html document and this is the way I have to do this.
How do i go about doing it?

my_python.py

```
user = "myname"
with open("../../html/forms/output.html") as output:
    print(output.readlines())
```

output.html

```
<h1>{user}</h1>
```

---

EXPECTED OUTPUT :

```
<h1>myname</h1>
```

---

ACTUAL OUTPUT :

```
<h1>{user}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f-string` is a syntax and not an object, and as a result - You can't convert a string to `f-string`.

If you know the names of the "variables" inside your template file, you can do:

```
output.read().format(user=user)
```